# Using mutate() to efficiently create data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this local data frame:

```
Source: local data frame [792 x 3]

         team       player_name  g
1     Anaheim       PERRY_COREY 31
2     Anaheim      GETZLAF_RYAN 22
3      Dallas        BENN_JAMIE 25
4  Pittsburgh     CROSBY_SIDNEY 20
5     Toronto       KESSEL_PHIL 27
6    Edmonton       HALL_TAYLOR 16
7      Dallas      SEGUIN_TYLER 24
8    Montreal      VANEK_THOMAS 19
9    Colorado LANDESKOG_GABRIEL 18
10    Chicago     SHARP_PATRICK 22
..        ...               ... ..
```

I want to be able to rank the teams based on their average number of goals (g) per player. Here is what I did (really feels suboptimal):

```
    library(dplyr)
      d1 <- select(df, team, g, player_name) 
      c1 <- count(d1, team, wt = g) 
      c2 <- count(d1, team, wt = n_distinct(player_name)) 
      c3 <- cbind(c1, c2[,2]) 
      c4 <- c3[,2] / c3[,3]
      c5 <- cbind(c3, c4)
      colnames(c5) <- c("team", "ttgpt", "ttnp", "agpp")
      c6 <- mutate(c5, rank = row_number(desc(c4)))
      c7 <- filter(c6, rank <=10)
      c8 <- arrange(c7, rank)
```

And here is the result of c8:

```
           team ttgpt ttnp     agpp rank
1       Chicago   177   23 7.695652    1
2      Colorado   164   23 7.130435    2
3       Anaheim   180   26 6.923077    3
4    NY_Rangers   153   23 6.652174    4
5        Boston   179   27 6.629630    5
6      San_Jose   157   25 6.280000    6
7        Dallas   155   25 6.200000    7
8     St._Louis   148   24 6.166667    8
9        Ottawa   160   26 6.153846    9
10 Philadelphia   140   23 6.086957   10
```

I would like to recreate this table with consistent use of `%>%`

See CSV for reproductible example: [playerstats.csv](http://www.elm.bi/playerstats.csv)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for.  You can replace all the assignments with `%>%` and a few minor changes if you're just looking for a way to make the table with chains.  Or are you looking for a better way to get the table?

Comment: I am looking for a better way to get the table, with chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok from what you said:

```
df<-read.csv("../Downloads/playerstats.csv",header=T,sep=",")

df %>% group_by(Team)  
   %>% summarise(ttgp=sum(G),ttnp=n_distinct(Player.Name),agp=sum(G)/n_distinct(Player.Name))
   %>% mutate(rank=rank(desc(agp))) 
   %>% filter(rank<=10) 
   %>% arrange(rank)

        Source: local data frame [10 x 5]

           Team ttgp ttnp      agp rank
1       Chicago  177   23 7.695652    1
2      Colorado  164   23 7.130435    2
3       Anaheim  180   26 6.923077    3
4    NY Rangers  153   23 6.652174    4
5        Boston  179   27 6.629630    5
6      San Jose  157   25 6.280000    6
7        Dallas  155   25 6.200000    7
8     St. Louis  148   24 6.166667    8
9        Ottawa  160   26 6.153846    9
10 Philadelphia  140   23 6.086957   10
```

Note that I am not sure what you mean with ttgpt and ttnp. Therefore, I tried to guess it.

Comment: This works with a dataframe. But what if I were to use an SQL table directly instead. When I try it I get: `Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function n_distinct(text) does not exist
LINE 3: FROM (SELECT "team", SUM("g") / N_DISTINCT("player_name") AS...
                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.)`

Comment: I am not sure, did you try to change n_distinct with length(unique(Player.Name))?

Comment: Yes but it does not work. I tried: `summarise(ttgp=sum(g),ttnp=length(unique(player_name)),agp=sum(g)/length(unique(player_name)))`

Comment: I sadly do not have a postgresql database on my computer. I can't really replicate your error. It seems to be a postgresql error. Did you check the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) on how to load postgresql data in dplyr?

Comment: I did. The postgresql database is loaded properly. In fact I just tried another example using my_tbl (sql table) directly and it worked: `my_tbl %>% select(team, g) %>% group_by(team) %>% summarise(g = sum(g)) %>% arrange(desc(g)) %>% mutate(rank = row_number(desc(g))) %>% filter(rank <= 10) %>%`

Comment: Ok, it seems like n_distinct have been introduced in [postgresql 9.0](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.0). Since I can't test, I suggest you to look for what is your version of postgresql. If you have one superior of 9.0 and the latest version of dplyr. Maybe consider report the issue on [github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues).

Comment: I have psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5 and the latest version of `dplyr`. I will report the issue on github. Many thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66963/discussion-between-zipp-and-steven-beaupre).